# Installing cygwin hangs on post install

Tags: cygwin

In the cygwin installation stuck installing at this path point
/etc/postinstall/0p_textlive_prep.dash

Any way to fix this? 
how to finish my installation.

Comment: What says `/var/log/setup.log.full` ?

Comment: @matzeri I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: In the cygwin directory tree  on the `/var/log`  directory,  setup stores the log of installations. Look on the files to know what and where the installation halted.